# Flutter: how to wait for entire async method to finish before the next line runs

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc

I'm running the script below:

```
TextButton(
  onPressed: () async {
    try {
      await BlocProvider.of<RoomCubit>(context).createRoom(test);
      await BlocProvider.of<PlayersCubit>(context) <---- Point 1
      .addPlayer(test.roomId, testPlayer);
      BlocProvider.of<NavigatorCubit>(context) <---- Point 2
                        .moveToLobby(context);
    } catch (e) {}
  },
  child: Text("Create room"),
)

class PlayersCubit extends Cubit<PlayerState> {
  PlayersCubit() : super(PlayerInitial());
    
  final PlayerRepository _playerRepository = PlayerRepository();
  Future<void> addPlayer(String roomId, Player player) async {
    emit(PlayerLoading());
    try {
      await _playerRepository.addPlayer(roomId, player);
      List<Player> playerList = await _playerRepository.playerList(roomId);
      emit(PlayerLoaded(player, playerList));
     } 
     catch (e) {}
  }
}
```

```dart
class NavigatorCubit extends Cubit<NavigatorState> {
  NavigatorCubit() : super(NavigatorInitial());
  late RoomState _roomState;
  late PlayerState _playerState;

  void moveToLobby(BuildContext context) {
    print("$_roomState, $_playerState");
    switch (_roomState is RoomLoaded && _playerState is PlayerLoaded) {
      case true:
        {
          Navigator.popAndPushNamed(
            context,
            "/Room",
          );
        }
        break;
      case false:
        {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        }
        break;
      default:
    }
  }

  void getRoomState(RoomState roomState) {
    _roomState = roomState;
  }

  void getPlayerState(PlayerState playerState) {
    _playerState = playerState;
  }
}
```

What I want it to do is emit PlayerLoaded from the PlayersCubit at the point 1, and then use that state in the NavigatorCubit at Point 2. However, even though I've put await at point 1 - the method at point 2 starts running before a state is emitted at point 1.

Is there a way I can make the next part wait before the state is emitted at point 1 without setting a timer?

Comment: Can you provide your implementations of your cubit and how you are accessing the state in the NavigatorCubit ?

Comment: Hey, I've added the NavigatorCubit in the post. And above the widget tree, I have a MultiBlocListener to update the states of RoomCubit and PlayerCubit within the NavigatorCubit. Hope that helps.

Comment: Actually, moveToLobby it is waiting for the call to addPlayer to finish, however it's not getting the new value of the PlayerState since it was called with an old context.

Comment: what I suggest is you pass the playerState and roomState as a parameter to moveToLobby function

Comment: I'm not familiar with Cubit, but I don't see anything obviously asynchronous that you're neglecting to `await`. (Enabling the [`unawaited_futures` lint](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/unawaited_futures.html) would be a good idea regardless.) If perhaps `emit()` doesn't trigger a state change synchronously, then perhaps look into using [`ChangeNotifier`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ChangeNotifier-class.html) and [`Completer`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Completer-class.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me was quite simple, passed in the playerState and roomState as parameters to moveToLobby function in the NavigatorCubit.

It seems like the async functions only actually wait for any steps that include the await, otherwise all other lines of code are run synchronously.